# Number sequence - arithmetic sequence difference constant - find formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

I searched a way to find out a formula to predict the nth number of a given sequence, but I did not find a way matching my case.

Arithmetic sequence:
I read that a good way is to find the constant difference.

Here is my sequence:
2,4,5,7,8,10,...
The differences are:
2,1,2,1,2,...

But I can't find a formula because the difference depends on the n variable and if the number is odd or even.
Docs I have read don't mention such case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the sequence as two separate sequences joined into one:

2,4,5,7,8,10...

=> 2,5,8,... and 4,7,10,...

If I denote the nth element in the original series as $a_n$, then :

If n is odd, $a_n = 2 + \frac{(n-1)}{2}*3$

If n is even, $a_n = 4 + \frac{n-2}{2}*3$

Comment: Ok I understand the way you used to find out. But I have to test n number before choosing the right formula. As I need it in a program, I can accept that way though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n = 2 + n + \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$$

When $n$ is odd, $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ increments. Note that in this case we have $a_0 = 2$.

Comment: As I want to start with n=1 I changed a bit the formula :
=ROUND(2+(n-1)+(n-1)/2)

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is odd$=2m+1$, the $2m+1$th term  $2+(2m+1-1)\dfrac32=3m+2=3\cdot\dfrac{n-1}2+2=\dfrac{3n+1}2$

If $n$ is even$=2m$, let $2m$th term $=am+b$

$\implies4=a+b,7=2a+b\implies a=3,b=1$

$\implies2m$th term $=3m+1=3\cdot\dfrac n2+1=\dfrac{3n+2}2$

So, the $n$th term in general is $\dfrac{3n+\dfrac32+\left(-\dfrac12\right)^n}2$

Comment: Ok, I also understand how did you end with the general formula.
I will also need to round the result.
=ROUND((3*n+3/2+POWER(-0,5;n))/2)